# Render XML document with XSL to a HTML page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have a xml document like below and I need to render it into HTML page. When I browse the XML from IE the HTML is rendered as expected with styling. If I load the xml document from c# code and pass to HTML page it just renders as plain text. What am I missing here?

XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='xslsheet.xsl'?>
<Document xmlns="org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
....
</Document>
```

C#

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C\SampleDocument.xml");
      var result = doc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an XML document does just that - it loads the data. It won't process a transform directive.

To do that you need to do an XSLT Transform. You can find the classes to do that on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).